# Do I need the battery to be present if notebook connected via Car Universal Laptop Power Adapter?

Tags: battery-charging, adapter, battery-operated

I am going for holiday and I want to use my old old Acer. The battery lasts for about 10 mins if not connected to the electricity outlet.

If the notebook is connected via Car Universal Laptop Power Adapter can I expect it to work as it was plugged into ordinary electricity outlet at my home?

Or the car battery can only charge the battery?

Comment: Off topic question, I think. It's better for SuperUser. Anyway stevenvh is right, you can use it, I did it too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since it's called an "Adapter" you can expect that you can use the laptop when plugged in, otherwise it would probably be called a "charger". I don't think there's any harm in trying it. If it's a proper adapter your laptop should be able to run as long as it's connected to the adapter (engine running).

Comment: Well, I think it's better to ask than just try if one needs to have 'working solution' before going to the holiday and before bying something I'll probably never use again. Thank you for your answer. Sounds goooooood.